# Chnaging the data attribute inside the div doesn't change image for 360 spin view

Tags: javascript, html

I am using js-cloudimage-360-view.min.js to get a 360 view of images. I am getting the images perfectly, but I am unable to change the images by clicking a button.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = 'test' style="width: 400px; margin: 100px auto;">
        <div
        class="cloudimage-360"
        data-folder="images/"
        data-filename="{index}.jpg"
        data-amount="22"
        >
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
        
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="js-cloudimage-360-view.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const img_box = document.querySelector('.cloudimage-360')
const btn = document.querySelector('button')


btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    img_box.dataset.folder = 'temp_images/'
    img_box.dataset.filename = '{index}.png'
    console.log(img_box.dataset)
})

console.log(img_box.dataset)
```

Here is the folder structure

- images
- temp_images
- index.html
- js-cloudimage-360-view.min.js
- main.js

Now in order for the 360 view to work, I have to specify the data-folder, data-filename and data-amount correctly inside the div tag and it is working fine. But I want to change the data-folder = 'temp_images/' and data-filename = '{index}.png' when the button is clicked to show a different set of images. I can see all the changes have been done correctly in the console, but the image remains the same. How can I get the images from different folders after clicking the button?

Here is the Github link

https://github.com/scaleflex/js-cloudimage-360-view

Here is a youtube tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEl4Q6dG7BA&t=111s

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to `destroy` the component, change the attributes, and then `init` it again.

```
window.CI360.destroy();
img_box.dataset.folder = 'temp_images/';
img_box.dataset.filename = '{index}.png';
window.CI360.init();
```

If it still doesn't work, then it would probably be best to [ask the author(s) directly](https://github.com/scaleflex/js-cloudimage-360-view/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like MV Agusta did on his site. Call the 360 ​​views of two different colors to the page at the same time and when the button is clicked, set the opacity of one (which you want to show) to 1 while the other (which you want to hide) to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the update function:

window.CI360.update(idOftheView, forceUpdate);

Update cloudimage 360 viewer instance.
For any update in source attributes after plugin initialization (e.g. data-folder, data-filename-x, data-amount-y), the plugin will re-init.

arguments:

idOftheView: string The id of the new view

forceUpdate: bool Force the view to reinitialize.